# what is the meaning of this sed command? sed '#012/ \n/g'

Tags: sed

I am not familiar with stream editor commands, and I am using an existing command. What exactly does this `sed` command do?

```
sed '#012/ \n/g'
```

Answer (score 5):

`#` starts a comment line in sed:

> ```
> #comment
> ```
>
> The comment extends until the next newline (or the end of a -e script fragment).

So, the command shouldn't do anything.